# how I can configure OpenSSL to 64 bit from 32 bit?

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, centos

I have openssl as third party lib, it works for 32 bit System. How can I configure it for 64 bit? I am using CentOs 6.02 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by configuring openssl to x86_64 by executing ./configure from openssl directory.

Comment: Sorry for commenting with my other account. I had forgotten my login credentials for Planet Developer. That's why I have created another account.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile openssl on an x86-64 machine.